# How to write Code that runs Periodically at certain intervals in .Net 5.0 C# or F#

Tags: c#, f#, scheduled-tasks, .net-5

I've written some Code in F# ( some in C# ) / .Net 5.0 and I am just running it as a console app currently and debugging it in visual studio.

I want it to

- Run by itself - every hour between 7 am and 6 pm Monday to Friday
- Be able to pause execution if need be.

What approach should I take with this?  When I was writing nodejs apps I used to put the command line command in to the windows scheduler.

Should I

- Use the windows scheduler and do it as a command line
- Write a Windows Service that does it
- something else?

I'm not sure what approach to take & I might be missing an approach that fits this task perfectly.

Comment: There are lots of frameworks out there that allows you to define Jobs and run them on schedule. Just to name a few: [Quartz.net](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet), [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire), [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler), etc.

Comment: By what mechanism will you initiate a pausing of the process?

Comment: I hadn't really thought that through ( pausing ) .  If it was a windows servcice I would pause the service - otherwise I guess I would have to set a database flag that is checked when running using one of the libraries mentioned above.

Comment: You can use builtin background services instead of frameworks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows to run the exe you can use the built in Task Scheduler. Regarding pausing the application, you can add a watcher to the app which will check for status before it runs. E.g. looks at a database or a centralised config file.